# Commodity index member weights (historical) for S&P GSCI and BCOM

Tags: data, bloomberg, index, commodities

Does anyone know a datasource for retrieving the historical index member weights for the two major commodity indices S&P GSCI and Bloomberg Commodity Index?
My institution provides access to Bloomberg and Thomson Reuters Eikon & Datastream but none of them has the respective data. Also, Google didn't deliver adequate results.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do these help? https://www.bloomberg.com/company/announcements/2015-target-weights-bloomberg-commodity-index-announced/ https://www.bloomberg.com/company/announcements/2016-target-weights-for-the-bloomberg-commodity-index-announced/ https://www.bloomberg.com/company/announcements/2017-target-weights-for-the-bloomberg-commodity-index-announced/

Comment: Thank you. That's certainly at good start, but I need data back to 2005/06.

Comment: The BCOM was started by AIG in 1998. It was taken over by UBS in May 2009, then by Bloomberg in 2014 (which has been publishing weights since then). For earlier info you might write to commodities@bloombergindexes.com Good Luck.